# Flex Builder : How to mark a warning as an error and aborting the build

Tags: warnings, flexbuilder

Is there a way by which I could make a warning behave
like an error in Flex Builder. In particular I am highly
worried about this warning :
**1100 : Assignment with conditional. Did you mean == instead of =?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way